# Knoockout computed observable doesnt update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable, modular-design

The following is a computed observable, and i am calling its write function, but the write doesnt update the value for the computed.

```
self.pagesToBeDisplayed = ko.computed({
    read: function () {

       var value = otherFile.PerformWork();
       return self.pages(value);
    }, write: function (totalCount) {
        var value = otherFile.PerformWork(totalCount);
        self.pages();
        self.pages(value) 
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
});
```

`otherFile.PerformWork()` is a function in other javascript file thta just updates `self.pages()`.

However, the value for self.pages and  self.pagesToBeDisplayed is still the older value. it doesnt get updated after the  `otherFile.PerformWork(totalCount)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your read function is currently writing to the `pages` observable instead of reading from it. To read, call the observable with no arguments: `self.pages()`. To write, call with one argument: `self.pages(value)`.

Your `write` function should be writing to the observable, and your `read` function should only be reading.